# Android configure and create sip calls programmatically

Tags: android

I am new to android and SIP. I want to create an application in android through which i can configure and create SIP calls programmatically. I want to encrypt that call. 
Android includes a full SIP protocol stack and integrated call management services but it will not manage sessions, transport-level communication.
So anybody who has good idea on SIP/Voip please kindly suggest me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [CSipSimple](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) program. It is an open source project.